# Copying Array Dimensions

Tags: arrays, cloning

I have a method, aModify(), that takes two object references, a1 and a2, and two String values, dim1, and dim2.

```
public static Object aModify(Object a1, String dim1, Object a2, String dim2);
```

a1 and a2 will be passed in as arrays, and dim1 and dim2 will be passed in as array dimensions (i.e dim1 = "0", dim2 = "0 0").

The goal behind this method is to take the array a2 at dim2 and copy the value(s) found there to a1 at dim1.

I have successfully copied the two arrays into new instances to manipulate, but I'm really confused on how to translate the String values dim1 and dim2 into array dimensions, and then use those dimensions to copy values.

So far, this is what I have for the method.

```
Object copy1 = Array.newInstance(a1.getClass().getComponentType(), Array.getLength(a1));
Object copy2 = Array.newInstance(a2.getClass().getComponentType(), Array.getLength(a2));

copy1 = MyUtility.aClone(a1);
copy2 = MyUtility.aClone(a2);
```

aClone() is a method I've written that returns a copy of whatever array that's passed into the method.

Arrays a1 and a2 also have different dimensions. The array a1 is a three-dimensional array where a2 is a four-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why your method does not take the arguments as `int` directly, but if you are just trying to convert the String `"0"` to an `int`, you can just use `Integer.parseInt()`.

If you want to convert the string `"0 0"` into two separate integers, you can use `String.split()` and then `Integer.parseInt()` on each element in the resulting array.

Based on your description of your goal, you probably want something like this?

```
int t_dim1 = Integer.parseInt(dim1);
String[] twodims = dim1.split(" ");
int t_dim2_1 = Integer.parseInt(twodims[0]);
int t_dim2_2 = Integer.parseInt(twodims[1]);
```

**Update**: It appears that the OP wants to handle arbitrary numbers of dimensions. For this, we need to be a little more clever. First, we write a helper function.

```
int[] parseAndConvert(String dims) {
    String[] dimArray = dims.split(" ");
    int[] retVal = new int[dimArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < retVal.length; i++) 
       retVal[i] = Integer.parseInt(dimArray[i]);
    return retVal;
}
```

Then, inside `aModify`, we will need to do something like this to find the element and set it. Note this is untested, but it should get you pretty close.

```
public static Object aModify(Object a1, String dim1, Object a2, String dim2) {
    int[] dims1 = parseAndConvert(dim1);
    int[] dims2 = parseAndConvert(dim2);
    // Find the element to copy.
    Object copyMe = a1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dims1.length; i++) 
         copyMe = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(copyMe, dims1[i]);

    // Find the nested array holding the object we want to overwrite
    Object target = a2;
    for (int i = 0; i < dims2.length - 1; i++) 
         target = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(target, dims2[i]);

    Array.set(target, dims2[dims2.length - 1], copyMe);
}
```

Comment: @mynorka, Let me know if this is what you were trying to do.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for, but that looks like it only works for one case. In my program, I will be running two separate cases. Case 1 will have dim1 being "0" and dim2 being "0 0", and the second case will have dim1 being "0 0" and dim2 being "0 0 0". I'm looking for a way to be able to copy whatever element is at index dim1 into the index dim2.

Comment: Please elaborate on the cases

Comment: Case 1: dim1 is the String "0" representing an index for the array a1, such as a1[0]. dim2 is the Stirng "0 0" representing the index a1[0][0] Case2: dim1 is the String "0 0" representing a1[0][0] and dim2 is String "0 0 0" representing a1[0][0][0]

Comment: @mynorka, Updated the answer. No guarantee the code will compile, but that should give you a sketch of what you need.

Comment: In your code, which array is the one being modified? copyMe or target?

Comment: @mynorka, `target` is being modified. `copyMe` is the value being written.